# Figure caption has line break problems when using subfig

Tags: captions, line-breaking, subfloats

I'm using the subfig package and I'm getting words that are broken in captions. Can anyone explain why, or how to stop it?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, draft]{report}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \subfloat[Sum frequency spectra taken at 18~\celsius\thinspace of a sample assembled from 18~\celsius\thinspace solution.]{\includegraphics[width=6cm, clip=true, trim=0cm 0cm 0cm 2cm]{TempHomeCold18}
        \label{fig:TempHomeCold18}}
    \qquad
    \subfloat[Sum frequency spectra taken at 18~\celsius\thinspace of a sample assembled from 35~\celsius\thinspace solution.]{\includegraphics[width=6cm, clip=true, trim=0cm 4cm 0cm 2cm]{TempHomeCold35}
        \label{fig:TempHomeCold35}}
    \qquad
    \subfloat[Sum frequency spectra taken at 18~\celsius\thinspace of a sample assembled from 40~\celsius\thinspace solution.]{\includegraphics[width=6cm, clip=true, trim=0cm 4cm 0cm 2cm]{TempHomeCold40}
        \label{fig:TempHomeCold40}}
    \qquad
    \subfloat[Sum frequency spectra taken at 18~\celsius\thinspace of a sample assembled from 45~\celsius\thinspace solution.]{\includegraphics[width=6cm, clip=true, trim=0cm 4cm 0cm 0cm]{TempHomeCold45}
        \label{fig:TempHomeCold45}}
    \qquad
    \caption Spectra obtained from hand-made samples on a cold stage.
\end{figure}
```

Which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hbr9.jpg). The "S" of Spectra is on the first line, and the remainder of the captions is on the next line.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I can not reproduce your error. Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Off topic: You might want to have a look on `\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\SI{18}{\celsius}
\end{document}`

Comment: Sorry, I got you wrong in the first place. Your error is that just `S` is handled as a caption. You have to write `\caption{Spectra obtained ...}` with braces all around it.

Comment: Oops! I feel silly now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig} % or use `\usepackage{subcaption}` which works better in combination with `hyperref`
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \subfloat[Sum frequency spectra taken at \SI{18}{\celsius} of a sample assembled from \SI{18}{\celsius} solution.]{\includegraphics[width=6cm, clip=true, trim=0cm 0cm 0cm 2cm]{TempHomeCold18}
        \label{fig:TempHomeCold18}}

    \subfloat[Sum frequency spectra taken at \SI{18}{\celsius} of a sample assembled from \SI{35}{\celsius} solution.]{\includegraphics[width=6cm, clip=true, trim=0cm 4cm 0cm 2cm]{TempHomeCold35}
        \label{fig:TempHomeCold35}}

    \subfloat[Sum frequency spectra taken at \SI{18}{\celsius} of a sample assembled from \SI{40}{\celsius} solution.]{\includegraphics[width=6cm, clip=true, trim=0cm 4cm 0cm 2cm]{TempHomeCold40}
        \label{fig:TempHomeCold40}}

    \subfloat[Sum frequency spectra taken at \SI{18}{\celsius} of a sample assembled from \SI{45}{\celsius} solution.]{\includegraphics[width=6cm, clip=true, trim=0cm 4cm 0cm 0cm]{TempHomeCold45}
        \label{fig:TempHomeCold45}}
    \caption{Spectra obtained from hand-made samples on a cold stage.} % <= you have forgotten those braces here. 
\end{figure}

% if you use a command without braces, just the next character is seen by the macro. Just try \textbf ab or \textit 12
\end{document}
```

[image]